# Dilemma between two database schemas for my marketplace rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a market place when a User can both buy and sell.
Of course he will not be able to buy his own products and once one of his product will be buyed there will be a quantity logic controller behind. However. I'm still stuck at modeling the schema.

At the moment i'm using this schema.

```
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_09_11_202223) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_orders_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "orders_products", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "order_id", null: false
    t.integer "product_id", null: false
    t.index ["order_id", "product_id"], name: "index_orders_products_on_order_id_and_product_id"
    t.index ["product_id", "order_id"], name: "index_orders_products_on_product_id_and_order_id"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "tagline"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "price"
    t.text "description"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_products_on_category_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_products_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Whit these models:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  belongs_to :user
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

So basically i'm about to use a HABTOM (has_and_belongs_to_many) associations between the table Orders and Products as you can see inside my models, because an order can have many products and a product can be in many orders( here i'm not sure xD, i think i'm wrong ). Anyway, my dilemma is this, since i've read on internet that in the most of the cases, in situations like this you can use the has_many :through association (HMTA), something  like this:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end

class User
  has_many :orders
  has_many :products, through: :orders
end

class Order
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :orders
  has_many :users, through: :orders
end
```

keep in mind that in my marketplace i want the people can both buy and sell, that's why a User can have many products but **the product must be unique and should belong to only one specific User**, for instance an old car, doesn't exist two cars exactly identical, that's why i used this association in my Product model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
end
```

so in the end what do you suggest me to do? should i switch from the HABTOM association to a HMTA? In this case, let's say i want to sell a product, how can i manage the User and Product association? is it possible just using a has_many :through association? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> the product must be unique and should belong to only one specific User

The point is that there needs to be **two** links between the `products` table and the `users` table.

You need the concept of a "seller" as well as "buyers" (or whatever you choose to name it).

Something like this:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User"
  has_many :buyers, through: :orders, class_name: "User"
end

class User
  has_many :orders
  has_many :products_bought, through: :orders, class_name: 'Product'
  has_many :products_sold, class_name: 'Product'
end
```

You can then add a uniqueness validation check on the product (possibly scoped to the `seller_id`?).

If one product had multiple sellers, then you could tweak this association slightly to use a more generic join table (i.e. rename the `orders` table). But you still need a clear distinction between the "sellers" and the "buyers".

Comment: When defining custom associations like this, you should also define an `inverse_of` on the association, so that Rails knows how to minimise the number of database queries made when accessing data between objects.